# ASP.net mvc5 multple actions on the same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to have multiple actions accessible from my Index page instead of having a separate view for each. But I'm not having much luck and I'm pretty much stuck.

My `BeginForm` can't resolve action `Create` nor can it resolve the controller `CategoriesController`.

This is my controller:

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _db.Categories.ToListAsync());
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Category category)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Categories.Add(category);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(category);
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Category category = await _db.Categories.FindAsync(id);
        if (category == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(category);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Category category = await _db.Categories.FindAsync(id);
        _db.Categories.Remove(category);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**And this is my view**

```
@using MultipleActionsSameView.Controllers
@model IEnumerable<MultipleActionsSameView.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table> 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CategoriesController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is the html form generated <form action="/Categories/Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> ?

Comment: @PaulZahra Negative.

Comment: in beginform the name of controller must be Categories without the suffix Controller

Answer (score 3):

use "Categories" instead of "CategoriesController"

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Categories", FormMethod.Post))
 {
      //your code
 }
```

sample here: [BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod%29)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to drop the "Controller" suffix of "CategoriesController" in Html.BeginForm ?

Answer (score 1):

To have multiple submit buttons in one view do the following:

Create an attribute...

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Mvc;

/// <summary>
/// The MultipleButtonAttribute class is a custom attribute to cater for a view form with multiple submit buttons.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Determines whether the action name is valid in the specified controller context.</summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="actionName">The name of the action.</param>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">Information about the action method.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the action name is valid in the specified controller context; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", this.Name, this.Argument);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[this.Name] = this.Argument;
            isValidName = true;
        }

        return isValidName;
    }
```

Then in the view I have multiple submit buttons and a form pointing at the index action like so...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Categories", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "mainForm" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Create" name="action:Create" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="action:Edit" />
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Create")]
public ActionResult Create()

[HttpGet]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Edit")]
public ActionResult Edit()
```

Comment: Is there any guide you know of that is good so I can read up more close to the subject?

Comment: Have a read of http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/Supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-ASPNET-MVC-view.aspx

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework